# Where can I watch all the Kamisama Kiss episodes, including the OVAs, in either english sub or dub?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

I was wondering if anyone knows where I can watch all of the Kamisama Kiss episodes online in either english sub or dub?

I'm pretty sure the anime consists of 2 seasons, and then 7 OVA episodes?

Please, I really love this anime, somebody please help me!

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only provide legal & official sites if they exist. Note however that those sites are usually geo-blocked (country restriction) due to the licensing terms itself

Answer (score 3):

*Kamisama Kiss* has been licensed for streaming by Funimation Entertainment.

- [**Hulu**](https://www.hulu.com/series/kamisama-kiss-442dc5d4-0253-4de6-8888-6ef32e30817f?entity_id=89c22fec-841b-44b7-8bde-833337bb09b0) streams 25 episodes (season 1 & 2) in *English dubbed* and *English subbed with Japanese audio*.
- [**Funimation Channel**](https://www.funimation.com/shows/kamisama-kiss/) (US only) streams 25 episodes (season 1 & 2) in *English dubbed* and *English subbed with Japanese audio*.

The OVAs do not seem to be licensed, so there is no way to watch it in English sub/dub legally.

Comment: It doesn't appear that Crunchyroll actually has it, just a page stating it's geo-blocked (I could find no information on anyone being able to view it currently); it is available in both sub and dub on Hulu, however, in addition to Funimation.

Comment: @AllisonC thanks for the heads-up, there's [a direct link to episode 1 on Crunchyroll](https://www.crunchyroll.com/kamisama-hajimemashita/episode-1-nanami-becomes-a-god-667635), though the comments tell that it is not in English subtitle.

Comment: Interesting, on my work computer I get an error (specific to Crunchyroll based on the vein-pop iconography used), rather than an actual video. My suspicion is that CR previously had it (I vaguely remember it being available to watch, though it didn't catch my attention at the time) but lost at least some of the licensing when they had their split with Funimation.